# Read JSON file from project folder in ChatBot

Tags: c#, json, azure-web-app-service, chatbot

I would like to read json files to present an adaptive card, but I am missing how to get the path to the files.
Like I have a card_a.json file in my wwwwroot folder.

```
public async Task<string> GetCardText(string cardName)
{
    var path = $"/wwwroot/{cardName}.json";
    if (!File.Exists(path))
        return string.Empty;

    using (var f = File.OpenText(path))
    {
        return await f.ReadToEndAsync();
    }
}
```

I tried `$"/wwwroot/{cardName}.json"`, `$"/{cardName}.json"` and `$"{cardName}.json"`, none of them worked.
I've read [this](https://github.com/microsoft/AdaptiveCards/issues/411) article, but didn't help, the sample fails here:

```
var path = HostingEnvironment.MapPath($"/Cards/{cardName}.json");
```

With an error: HostingEnvironment does not contain a definition for MapPath. Adding using System.Web didn't solve this issue. VS says that adding this is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the cardname.json file need to reside in the wwwroot folder? You could save a lot of permission and path problems by storing them in the application root, or a subfolder of that.

Comment: No, I can put it anywhere.